# How to create Dynamic Table in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am working on a project in R where I need to create a dynamic table that updates based on changing data but don't know how to create it.

```
data <- tibble(
  Date_Time = c("2023-06-14 09:43:06", "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16", "2023-06-14 09:43:19"),
  Thermal_Energy_Intensity = c(407.3212, 407.3212, 407.3212, 407.3212, 407.3212),
  Specific_Heat_Capacity = c(223282.7, 223282.7, 223282.7, 223282.7, 223282.7),
  Heat_Absorption_Capacity = c(386245.8, 386245.8, 386245.8, 386245.8, 386245.8)
)
```

I want to create something this:

Example:

[image]

Do I need to use **Shiny** package to create this dynamic table like structure

Comment: You could do this using `gganimate`

Comment: Do you want to expand the existing tibble by adding rows to it, or to display one row at a time in an animation?  To me, your text suggests the former, your example the latter...

Comment: @Limey I want to display one row at a time in an animation.

Comment: Where should this table be output to?

Comment: @KonradRudolph - In the viewer section of R studio. I got the answer now but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using `gganimate`. You could use `transition_time` on your date_time column instead of the manual transition i've used. basically you make a void ggplot, add some text to it and aniimate it :)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)


df <- tibble(
  Date_Time = c("2023-06-14 09:43:06", "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16", "2023-06-14 09:43:19"),
  Thermal_Energy_Intensity = runif(5)*400,
  Specific_Heat_Capacity = runif(5)*223282.7,
  Heat_Absorption_Capacity = runif(5)*386245.8
) %>% mutate(Date_Time = as.POSIXct(Date_Time)) %>% arrange(Date_Time) %>% mutate(row_index = row_number())

p <- ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0("Specific heat capacity = ",Specific_Heat_Capacity), x= 0,y=1.5,)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0("Heat absorption capacity = ",Heat_Absorption_Capacity), x= 0,y=1.75)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0("Thermal energy intensity = ",Thermal_Energy_Intensity), x= 0,y=2.0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,2)) +
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "{current_frame}") +
  transition_manual(row_index)
  

animate(p, renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

[image]